# What is the "cost" of deeply nested folders in ext4?

Tags: filesystems, directory-structure, ext4

I was running into performance problems with hundredthousands of files in single directories when I needed to do certain wildcard matches.  From my applications point of view, a simple solution is to place the files in deeply nested folders.

The expected upper bound for the total number of folders across the whole hierarchy is 9^30.  It can be assumed that this limit will never be reached (see comment below). The number of folders will just simply grow as files are added.

Question: Are there any implications from filesystem perspective, when vast ammounts of  folders are created on an ext4 filesystem?  How much space is consumed by eg. a folder just containing another folder?  Will I run into trouble because of too much metadata?

*(There are certain advantages from my apps perspective with above structure compared to for example hash-based folders in a more simple hierarchy, I am aware of "better" methods to organise data)*

Comment: Is a database not an option? This sounds like it would be much faster in a database.

Comment: If you create 1,000 directories per second then it takes you about 10^18 years (one hundred million times the life time of the universe) to create 9^30 directories. What are you talking about?

Comment: @HaukeLaging I did not mean to say that I am creating that number of folders, I tried to give an estimate on the upper bound.  To reprphrase it according to your comment: The upper bound is not binding, will I run into problems after creating a certain number of folders.  I will edit the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Each folder consumes one inode (256 byte) and at least one block (probably 4096 byte). The bigger problem may be access time over several hierarchy layers.

The performance problem is probably not due to the folder size but to pathname expansion. Pathname expansion has two problems:

1. It sorts the results (which cannot be disabled) which takes a disturbingly long time for huge amounts of items.
2. It creates (depending on the kind of usage) illegal command lines (too many items).

You should address this on application level. Read 100 file names at a time (unsorted, with `find` or `ls -U`) and sort these small groups if necessary. This also allows for parallel reading from disk and CPU usage.

If you really need pathname expansion and / or sorting then you may speed up the process a lot (if the files change seldom only) by adding the files to their (empty) directories in sort order.

Comment: Thank you.  I have played around with with find & du and the output  of filtering on files vs. total size is consistent with the consumption you stated.  I am happy with the performace of the current nested setup, but I will run into capacity constraints faster than I thought.  So, unfortunately, I have to give up the simple design.

Answer (score 8):

Ext4 copes a bit better at large directories than previous versions but still bogs down after 10,000 files or so in the same directory. Separating out files in a directory hierarchy a few levels deep is a common solution to maintain the performance. Each depth increment requires an extra indirection when looking up a file, but the width increases exponentially with the depth.

For example, if your files have names consisting only of letters, digits and a few punctuation signs, instead of putting them all in the same directory, create subdirectories based on the first two characters of the file name. That is, the file `foobar` is stored in `fo/foobar`. If you still have too many files in the subdirectories, increase the depth: `fo/ob/foobar`, and so on. You'll have to do benchmarks to figure out how many characters to split after and at what depth to stop.

There are a lot of potential directories, and most will end up empty. So rather than creating all directories at the beginning, create them on demand. For example, if you need to create the file `foobar`, then create the directory `fo` if it doesn't already exist, then do the same for `fo/ba`, and then store `foobar` in `fo/ba/foobar`.

Unless the files are tiny (less than 4kB), the directories will represent a negligible amount of space. Even with tiny files, as long as you don't overdo the depth, there will be far fewer directories than files. However, if you have a huge number of tiny files, it's a sign you should be using a database instead.

Comment: Do you have a citation for the 10k directory size performance?  I'm looking for such a performance test.

Comment: @JohnFranklin Just personal experience. The slowdown is gradual, so don't take this as a precise figure, just an order of magnitude.